# Rails 3 show text field unless it has just "@"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, textfield

In my Rails 3 web app, I have a Twitter text field in one of the forms and on the user page it displays it.

```
<%= f.label :twitter, "Twitter Username" %>
<%= f.text_field :twitter, :value => "@" %>
```

And on the user page:

```
<% if @user.twitter?  %>
  <div class="twitter"><%= @user.twitter %></div>
<% end %>
```

The problem is, when a user doesn't enter their Twitter username into the field, it keeps `@` in the field and displays it on the user page. Because of this I would like to make it so if it just has `@` then it doesn't display it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the `@` value gets persisted into the database if the user doesn't specify a twitter name, right? Are you sure you want that?

You could, in the controller, when saving the user, do something like:

```
user.twitter = params[:user][:twitter] unless params[:user][:twitter] == "@"
```

This will ensure that the `User#twitter` field only gets set if something is specified.

But to answer your question specifically, you can do something like this in the view:

```
<%= @user.twitter == "@" ? "(not provided)" : @user.twitter %>
```